# Can you solve a trig equation with a variable both inside a trig function and outside one?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the equation:

$$d=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{sin(t)}{4}$$

I'm completely failing at how to get this in terms of $t$

I only care about it for values of $0<t<2\pi $

I've seen the graph so I know there's an inverse of it but I'm struggling on getting there

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want $t$ as a function of $d$?

Comment: Yes, I want $t$ as a function of $d$

Comment: You cannot use elementary methods to isolate $t$ here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. If we look at a simpler version of the problem,  $$\sin(t) = t,$$ we could maybe divide both sides by $t$ to get $$\frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 1.$$ Then we could take the inverse sinc function(if it exists) on both sides. If sinc inverse exists, then I think that it should be restricted in its domain in order to be a function.

However with a problem like this, I do not think it is possible to isolate $t$ or to get the inverse sinc function.